# How to install custom stable ICS rom on galaxy S2 (rar file)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, rom

So if you follow [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOaj6x_ZeMA) link then apparently this is an unofficial stable release of ICS for the galaxy S2. Also it's been tested by the members of XDA and they also say it's legit.

So if I want to test this out, the link to the download is [here](http://hotfile.com/dl/137945339/4838e6e/Official_Android4.0_forSamsung_GS2_Ice-Cream-byAndroidsRoms.rar.html), how do you install the rar file? You flash it with Odin right? I loaded some custom roms on my phone a while ago but I can't remember if you flash rar files with Odin or put it on your micro sd and run it from there..(Although I think that you do with zip files.)

Any advice would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any obvious mention of that particular SGS2 ICS ROM on [XDA's SGS2 pages](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1056) but there are a few other ICS ROMs there, all with install instructions in their main post.

Have you tried opening the RAR file with something like WinRAR or WinZip to see if there are instructions or a readme inside it?

Comment: Yep, you can flash ZIPs through recovery and TARs through Odin, but nothing uses RARs.